# the number of boys in the class is fewer than that of girls- correct or not?

Tags: adjectives

The number of boys- countable or uncountable? I'm confused with this sir.

Answer (score 2):

There are **fewer** boys than girls in the class.
There are **more** girls than boys in the class.
The number of boys in the class is **less** than the number of girls.
The number of girls in the class is **greater** than the number of boys.

A number can't be fewer or more; it's either less or greater. It's a number. One number.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

"Number" as a quantificational noun is non-count, though it has both singular and plural forms. Its status as a non-count noun is evident from the fact that it can't take cardinal numbers: there's no *"one/two/nine numbers of boys". Which means that the whole NP "the number of boys in the class" ..." is likewise non-count.